Google Custom Search Engine refinement is not working
I use Google Custom Search Engine on my website. To improve the search, I use an Refinement attribute that I pass to sections of the site. Previously, when the search and results were on the same page, everything worked fine. However, if I display the search results on a different page, the filtering parameters are ignored.
My code on page with search form
<div class="gcse-searchbox-only"
     data-defaultToRefinement="post-type"
     data-as_sitesearch="*.search.com/partition/"
     data-resultsUrl="site.com/searchpage">
</div>

Code on results page
<div class="gcse-searchbox-only"
         data-defaultToRefinement="post-type"
         data-as_sitesearch="*.search.com/partition/"
         data-resultsUrl="site.com/searchpage">
    </div>

<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"></div>

